# Max and Min sum

Tags: c++

I have written a code to find max and min sum that can be calculated from four numbers out of five numbers in c++

[image: code]

but it doesn't generate the desired output on large values e.g. input I give and output I get?

[image]

Comment: It would be best if you would put the code and output into the question. Then people can copy/paste the code and look at it.

Comment: Please paste the formatted code in the original question.

Comment: You also should work on your code alignment. I'm sure there are bugs that you just missed because of your horrible code alignment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having overflow issues. The max value for long type  is 2,147,483,647 on 32 bit systems and on Windows 64 bit (see [this reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os/)). Adding up all the values you entered gives 3,001,208,382. I am able to reproduce your error (`min` is negative) on my Mac by changing `long` to `int` (thereby causing overflow trying to store the numbers as 32 bit values). Try changing

```
long a[5], max=0, min=10000, sum;
```

to

```
long long a[5], max=0, min=10000, sum; // long long is 64bit on Win
```

and see if you get non-negative values. Since there is no subtraction in your algorithm and you only entered positive values, the only way to get `sum` to be negative is overflow.

Also, with the numbers you entered `sum` will never be less than `10000`. I would suggest initializing your min and max differently. Perhaps, set `min` and `max` equal to `sum` after the first inner loop iteration.

Comment: even after using double instead of long the minimum sum turns out to be negative

Answer (score 0):

Use `long long int` or `unsigned long long int`

They have higher ranges:

`long long int:` -9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

`unsigned long long int:` 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: I guess there is some logical error in the code which I'm not able to find out.

Answer (score 0):

1. The way your code is aligned is ugly and error prone.
2. Those `for` without brackets are confusing.
3. It is probably not an [onverflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). (`long`s work on my machine) [image: ssoguy.png]

What you want to do is read five values in input and output the `min`, the `max` and the `sum`. There are several ways to do it.

One of the ways is to check if the values are smaller or greater than the current `min/max` as you read them and add them to the `sum` afterwards. You need to check if compare them to the current `min/max`, not to the `sum`.

```
if(a[i] > max)
    max = a[i];
else if (a[i] < min)
    min = a[i];

sum += a[i];
```

Another (better) way to do it is using [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and use the methods it provides to retrieve what you need.

My recommandation is to start learning cpp from a better [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It looks like the OP is using Windows which has smaller `long` than other 64bit systems.